# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'category_affiliation')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I created a login function using redux state, but the problem is when I logged in, I get an error message of this. In my Sidebar.jsx. It seems like, I can't immediately render the data `admin`,

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'category_affiliation')

Sidebar.jsx

```
const Sidebar = () =>{

  const { admin } = useSelector((state) => state.admin);
  let techSuperAdmin = admin && admin.techAdmin ? admin.techAdmin : false;
  let techAdminCategory = admin && admin.category_affiliation ? admin.category_affiliation : null;
}
```

This is my HandleLogin

```
  const handleLogin = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      await LoginUser(userAdmin, dispatch)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

MyAdminSlice.jsx

```
export const adminSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'admin',
    initialState: {
        admin: null,
        isFetching : false,
        isError: false,
        isSuccess: false,
        isUpdated: false,
        isMessage: "",
    },
    reducers: {
        resetState: (state) =>{
            state.admin = null;
            state.isFetching = false
            state.isError = false
            state.isSuccess = false
            state.isUpdated = false
            state.isMessage = ""

        },
        loginStart: (state)=>{
            state.isFetching = true;
            state.isError = false;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) =>{
            state.isFetching = true;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.admin = action.payload,
            state.isMessage = "";
        },
        loginFailure: (state, action) =>{
            state.isSuccess = false;
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.isMessage = action.payload;

        }, 
        logOut: (state) =>{
            state.admin = null;
        },

    }

})

export const {resetState, loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure, logOut } = adminSlice.actions;
export default adminSlice.reducer
```

EDIT:

This is the data I'm getting

[image]

Comment: Is destructuring `admin` from `state.admin` intentional? Do you have a nested admin object in state? If not, it should be  `const admin = useSelector((state) => state.admin);`

Comment: I have object inside admin,

Comment: The image you attached is of the state, which has only one `admin` object inside. So you can directly access it like so `const admin = useSelector((state) => state.admin);` and then access it's inner properties like `admin.techAdmin`

Answer (score 0):

you can do below changes, as in your response there is no `category_affiliation`.

you can add optional chaining, if key exist then only read it.

learn more about
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
const Sidebar = () =>{

  const { admin } = useSelector((state) => state.admin);
  let techSuperAdmin = admin && admin?.techAdmin ? admin?.techAdmin : false;
  let techAdminCategory = admin && admin?.category_affiliation ? admin?.category_affiliation : null;
}
```